# Why is it that there are sharper Maxima with higher number of slits in a grating

Tags: optics

Uff, thats kinda a tricky question to express. But why is it? The intensity-distribution-function looks also complicated so I can't really derive it from the equation. Someone has an intuitive explanation?

Comment: Are you familiar with https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fourier_analysis ?

Comment: nope, sorry. Still gotta pick up.

Comment: No worries. A proper answer to your question will refer to Fourier theory. But this acoustic version might help get you started: the spectrum of a sharp brief sound (eg a gunshot) has *lots* of frequency components. Conversely, the simplest spectrum, that of a sine wave, has a single component, (the frequency of the wave), but a pure sine wave is eternal (it's defined from $t=-\infty$ to $+\infty$). Your scenario is similar, except it's about waves in space & spatial frequency, rather than waves in time & temporal frequency.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the double slit experiment the photons that enter the slits all end up in the bright areas, there are no photons in the dark. Feynman proposed the photons "look" at all possible pathways and choose the ones that are most probable, the paths highly tend to be the ones that are of length that is an integer multiple of the wavelength, intuitively these photons travel in space from atom A to atom B like a musical note travels on a piano or guitar string. Also the photon tends to want to travel a shorter distance.

The "looking" process involves an excited electron causing disturbances in the EM field (called virtual photons), when there are many slits the EM field concentrates (resonates) in the middle, i.e. the other paths thru the slits are more difficult to traverse due to their tighter path lengths and become less probable.